# Running a simple website on Asp IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, model-view-controller

I want to run my first project on visual studio 2015 (project type :
web ->asp.net mvc 5 ,with empty or mvc template ) ,yet when I press debug ,suppose to have a simple hello world or my view ,i have the error 404 the resource cannot be found ,
note : I tried follow a previous stack overflow instructions of enabling IIS still having 404.

Answer (score 0):

solved by specifying the startup project.[image]